# Как работает from ... import ...?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Совсем недавно поставил для себя новую цель: изучить работу импортов в Python. Поставил эту цель в связи с ошибками в скриптах. Я создал пакет, состоящий из:

```
package1:
   __init__.py
   module1.py
   package2:
      __init__.py
      module2.py
```

Мне нужно было в файле *`package2\__init__.py`* импортировать файл *`module2`*, используя конструкцию `from . import module2`. Но уже здесь возникала ошибка, которую я сумел устранить, запустив файл из предыдущей директории или импортировав его в файл *`package1\__init__.py`*.

*Отсюда возникает первый вопрос*: ***Почему при импорте файла *`module2`* в файл *`package1\__init__.py`*, находясь в директории *`package2`*, вызывается ошибка *`ImportError`*, а находясь в директории *`package1`* импорт проходит успешно? С чем это связано?***

Следующим мне нужно было в файле *`package2\module2.py`* импортировать файл предыдущей директории *`package1\module1.py`*. Для этого я использовал ту же конструкцию *`from .. import module1`*. Я рассчитывал на то, что всё пройдёт успешно, так как такой способ был приведён в документации.

*Теперь можно перейти ко второму вопросу*: ***Почему файл *`package1\module1`* не импортируется в файле *`package2\module2`* с использованием конструкции *`from .. import module1`*? Как это можно исправить, и вообще, есть ли какие-либо другие варианты добиться того же результата?***

**Я только прошу Вас, не нужно мне писать способы импорта с использованием магических переменных `__path__` или `__package__` или переменной `sys.path`, я написал этот вопрос, чтобы разобраться в системе импорта и понять свои ошибки. Мне нужно разъяснение импорта через конструкцию `from ... import ...` и ответы на мои вопросы!**

***Заранее СПАСИБО!***

Answer (score 1):

Магии тут нет. Import может читать модули только из текущей директории(откуда запущена консоль, грубо говоря), откуда он вызывается или всех путей, которые указаны в переменной PATH. Вот и всё.

Import не может импортировать откуда вы захотите (т.е. с абсолютно любого места), ему нужно прописывать пути, где искать ваши модули.

В интернетах предостаточно информации. А вообще - для этого существует документация Python.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html